# Can anyone clarify the Event handler execution from a field defaulting to row persisted or refer me to a source link

Tags: events, handler, acumatica

I would like to know how each event handler works and when it triggers.
And also which event is best to populate the customized Unbound field.
I have been using Rowselected event for Unbound field.
According to some sources, Rowselected is used only for the UI controls.

So, In which event I should use to calculate and populate the Unbound field with out using PXFormula like Attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started.

[Working with Events](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=106557db-e5f6-416c-8872-5ef3de9bf433)

See the sequence of entries from the link above for more detail on the order of events. For example here is the image from [Sequence of Events: Update of a Data Record](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=8f77ddc6-374b-4ad9-be20-a282febf88f8):

[image]

For unbound fields you should use the [PXUnboundFormulaAttribute](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=1247ee11-793e-41fb-e126-788cd13b4bc4) or the [FieldSelecting](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=7afeed34-d321-02e8-bc8a-853d66732de3) or [RowSelecting](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=3914d39a-0394-c506-92b5-3bbe3b044cbb) events for calculated values.

Comment: Thanks you Brendan.

Comment: Don't forget if this helped answer your question to mark as answer.